# translate a variable (which is used in Text())

Tags: swiftui, translate

i have this code here. Normally it is just a Text(question), but then the contents of my variable question will not be translated. There must be a better way...but i don't know how.
Of course "question" will have diffent contents...

```
if question == "text to be translated" {
                        Text("text to be translated")  // works

                    } else {
                        Text(question) // does not work

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible variant (old good `NSLocalizedString`) that still works (tested with Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3)

```
Text(NSLocalizedString(question, comment: ""))
```

other possible variant (tested in same environment) is

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(question))
```