# NSLocalizedString and value with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to localize a Text view with a value inside without success!

Here's what I'm usually do:

```
// ContentView.swift

Text("Tomato")
/* replaced by */
Text(NSLocalizedString("text-tomato", comment: ""))

// Localizable.strings (en)

"text-tomato" = "Tomato";
```

But with a value inside I don't know how to proceed:

```
// ContentView.swift

Text("3 Tomatoes")
/* or */
Text("\(tomatoes.count) Tomatoes")
/* replaced by */
Text(NSLocalizedString("\(tomatoes.count) text-tomatoes", comment: ""))

// Localizable.strings (en)

"%@ text-tomatoes" = "%@ Tomatoes";
/* or maybe */
"(tomatoes.count) text-tomatoes" = "%@ Tomatoes";
/* or maybe */
"%@ text-tomatoes" = "(tomatoes.count) Tomatoes";
```

I have tried to use `%@`, `%lld`, `value`, etc without success. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042837/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342131/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61383558/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187817/12299030, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623431/12299030 for different examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an answer right after posting my question:

```
// ContentView.swift

Text("3 Tomatoes")
/* or */
Text("\(tomatoes.count) Tomatoes")
/* replaced by */
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("%lld text-tomatoes", comment: ""), tomatoes.count))

// Localizable.strings (en)

"%lld text-tomatoes" = "%lld Tomatoes";
```

It's working like a charm!

Other example: [Localization with String interpolation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62042521/localization-with-string-interpolation-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `NSLocalisedString` with SwiftUI, use normal `Text()`:

```swift
Text("Tomatoes", comment: "TODO item")

Text("\(viewModel.tomatoesCount, specifier: "%lld") Tomatoes",
    comment: "TODO item with number")
```

Do not ignore comments, it will help with context during translation.

Read more at [Preparing views for localization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preparing-views-for-localization.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alexxnd

This is what worked for me:

```
let notAllowedChar = String(format: NSLocalizedString("TextfieldNotAllowedChar %@", comment: ""), char)
```

"TextfieldNotAllowedChar %@" -> "No permitido el character '%@'"

---

I was having trouble with:

```
SwiftUI.LocalizedStringKey.FormatArgument(storage: SwiftUI.LocalizedStringKey.FormatArgument.Storage.value( ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).